# Can I trust in X/SWAT PPA?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, ppa

This is the repository for get the lastest NVIDIA propietary. Im not happy with the repos one because Im having problems with unity, sometimes it lags and freezes. But I want to know if I should trust.

What do you say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repo is maintained by [a Canonical employee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Sarvatt) so as far as "trust" goes, you *should* be pretty safe with this one.

But whether or not it fixes things, is another question. It could make things worse, but you can always use `ppa-purge` to remove the PPA and reset the packages back to their sock Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Lol Is a Canonical employee? nothing to say, this is recommended. Dont worry buddy I had installed it in the past without issues. The issue is that unity get slow when I Wake Up my Laptop and I dont know if unity3d is buggy or its a NVIDIA problem. So I will update the driver with this repo for the doubts.