# Using Ubuntu-x-swat PPA solved my problem. Can I be sure the commands I ran are safe?

Tags: ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I trust in X/SWAT PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113051/can-i-trust-in-x-swat-ppa)

Are these commands safe?

I was getting logged out by Ubuntu, and these commands saved me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Do you mind telling why did you use them?

Comment: Sure, after installing adicional drivers and setting resolution and refresh rate, I'd get logged off after a while, losing any work I was doing. After typing this commands, it's fine, I don't even have to set the refresh rate after login in anymore! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean by safe, but in general, there is no problem with this.  You have added an extra source of packages (a PPA) where packages and updates which have not (yet) been released to the general public are hosted.  In this case, the package are related to the graphical environment and your graphics card.  (I also used this PPA to try solve some problems with my graphics card.)

The key here is that this is a fairly well-known/trusted PPA.  In theory, someone could host a PPA and put malicious code in it, but he would usually be called out pretty quickly for it on a public forum like this.

There is also some slight risk, in that there is a higher risk of bugs in code that is still in a PPA, rather than released in the mainstream package repositories, because it might not have been tested as thoroughly yet, and less users will have been using it to discover other bugs or problems with it.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, know I know when I install Ubuntu for good it's safe to type those commands.